# Dreamweaver has advised there is a syntax error in bootstrap js

Tags: javascript

Hello Dreamweaver is showing a syntax error in bootstap js

here are the offending lines

```
 const toType = obj => {
    if (obj === null || obj === undefined) {
      return `${obj}`;
    }
```

the error is on the top line and looks like its a missing curly btacket

Comment: What is your question? If there is a bug in that library this is not the place to report such a bug

Comment: how can I correct the syntax error

Answer (score 2):

```
const toType = obj => {
    if (obj === null || obj === undefined) {
      return `${obj}`;
    }
} // <= that is the bracket that is missing
```

Comment: Dream weaver is still showing syntax error on top line

Comment: could u post your html code pls?